# How to control dependency gem versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created a new AWS ubuntu server and tried to install Unicorn(using salt-stack and manually) on it but it failed with the following error.

```
[INFO    ] Running state [unicorn] at time 12:18:59.787564
[INFO    ] Executing state gem.installed for unicorn
[INFO    ] Executing command 'gem list unicorn' in directory '/home/ubuntu'
[INFO    ] Executing command '/usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv rehash ' in directory '/home/ubuntu'
[INFO    ] Executing command 'gem install unicorn --version 4.8.2 --no-rdoc --no-ri' in directory '/home/ubuntu'
[ERROR   ] Command 'gem install unicorn --version 4.8.2 --no-rdoc --no-ri' failed with return code: 1
[ERROR   ] stderr: ERROR:  Error installing unicorn:
    rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
[ERROR   ] retcode: 1
[ERROR   ] Could not install gem.
```

I created  a similar server a few months back and the installation worked fine. It failed because while installing `unicorn gem(4.8.2)` it installed `rack gem(1.6.4)` as unicorn dependency. rack 1.6.4 depends on ruby 2.2.2 so the installation fails.

I installed `rack version 1.6.2` manually and then tried to install `unicorn 4.8.2` and It worked.

Now the question is how to avoid this inconsistency, one solution I can think of is to manually install all the dependency gems but that would require much effort. Is there any way to lock down on the gem version and also gem dependency versions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use bundler? If not take a look at it http://bundler.io/.

With it you can define the versions of gems in the Gemfile. When you run `bundle install` a file named Gemfile.lock will be generated with all the gem versions and their dependencies locked.

Comment: I use bundler but the problem is some gems I install as part of infrastructure like unicorn, capistrano, backup, mailer and some gems as part of application. the application gems are being installed using bundler but not the infrastructure gems

Comment: I would add all needed gems for the application to it's Gemfile, because that way the application carries all it's dependencies. It's fragile to install dependencies outside the application IMHO.